# Integrated Facebook chat on Windows Phone warning sounds scary, is data sent to Microsoft's servers?

Tags: facebook

When I add a Facebook account to my phone, I get this permission request from Facebook:

> Microsoft will receive the following info: your public profile, friend list, News Feed, birthday, work history, current city, photos, videos and website and your friends' birthdays, work histories, current cities, photos, videos and websites.

Is "Microsoft" here referring to the company, or merely the application name?

i.e., is all of this data sent over to Microsoft's servers, or is it kept on Facebook's servers and merely accessed by the app without any of the the data going through Microsoft servers?

Comment: Does Facebook data appear in the People Hub or just the Facebook and Messenger app?

Comment: @NeilTurner: I think it's also in the people hub? The "app" here is integrated in the phone and it's from Microsoft, I'm not talking about apps from Facebook itself.

Answer (score 2):

Once you enable Facebook chat on your WP, you can see an app is added to your Facebook account  as other apps (like photos or candy crush) and all these apps will use your all personal information. They can save all the info to their server. But with my experience Microsoft is able to show you all the history of your chat on Microsoft account. That means they are storing all the chats done through Microsoft app and not the chat happened from Facebook chat app.

"Microsoft" here referring to the Facebook app.

In WP 8.1, Integrated Facebook chat is removed.

Comment: Well, I'm fine if the only thing they store on their server is the chats I do on their integrated app. But I guess what I'm wondering about is whether Microsoft's servers will also be receiving my friends' birthdays, my friends list, etc., not just the activity I have through the integrated app.

Comment: Your microsoft (live/hotmail/outlook) calendar and contact list will be in sync with FB but no wall content.

Comment: Hmm how sure are you about that? Like why do they want to see so much information though, if the only thing they need is a calendar and contact list?

Comment: @MaheshMankar there is wall content on the "what's new" tab for each contact in the address book.

Comment: @Mehrdad It may be that Facebook have added new permissions to their system, and implicitly added it to all historical apps "so that they can add the new stuff to their app". Most of the information does show up somewhere in the people hub though.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: I'm still unclear about this: will my friends' birthdays, for example, be sent to Microsoft servers? I can't tell if that falls under "calendar", "wall content", or something else, and whether or not they are sent to Microsoft servers...

Comment: @Mehrdad Friends' birthdays get added to your calendar when you connect to Facebook.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: And therefore sent to Microsoft servers?

Comment: Yes, sent to Microsoft server.